Ghost comedy set in a summer family vacation seaside cottage around 1970ish
I am searching for a ghost comedy that was on regular TV when I was young. Maybe 1970 or 1971, or around that time. It was color and the characters spoke English.
A family spends the summer in a seaside cottage. The resident ghost are always fighting by throwing things at each other. The fight that I really remember is in the kitchen with pots and pans and flour flying. It was a female ghost throwing things at a male ghost.
The teenage son always gets blamed for the messes. Only he can see the ghost not the parents. Of course the parents do not believe their son when he attempts to explain the reason for the messes that are being made.
The son meets a neighborhood girl that, being able to also see the ghost, thinks she knows how to get rid of the ghost. 
The rich uncle of the vacationing family shows up with his yacht. The female ghost falls in love with the uncle and kills him, by drowning, so that they can be together. When the family leaves to return home, they pass the neighborhood girl sitting in the cemetery pulling petals off of a flower.
It was a funny movie. I remember liking it very much but I do not know the name of the Movie or the names of any of the cast. If anyone knows, please Help. Thanks. I would really like to add it to my collection of ghost movies.

Gotta say, it doesn't sound funny. Ghosts murdering people...perhaps as a child you didn't understand it?

@Paulie_D Well, that's relative. It depends on the tone of the show. Addams Family, for example, has a bunch of sinister, torture related, conversation. It was still funny, though.

Could it possibly be: The Spirit Is Willing (1967) ?
(it IS tagged as both comedy and horror)

When Ben and Kate Powell (Sid Caesar and Vera Miles) rent a haunted
  New England house by the sea, their son Steve (Barry Gordon) gets
  blamed for the destruction caused by three unruly ghosts.

